# STATIC_ROOT = '/static/' collects my static files outside my workspace directory

Tags: python, django, static

i have in my settings.py used

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/static/'
```

to collect the static files 
this is my static_path settings

```
STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
```

when i run the collect static code django makes a static folder outside my workspace folder,should't it collect all the static files in the static folder which i have already created?

Comment: Have you defined `STATICFILES_DIRS`?

Comment: this is what i have STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    STATIC_PATH,
)

Answer (score 2):

I think you've confused the `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATIC_URL` and `STATICFILES_DIRS` setttings.

To tell Django to serve your static files from `example.com/static/`, set

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

You shouldn't set `STATIC_ROOT = '/static'`. This is telling Django to collect your static files in `/static/` on your disk, which *is* outside of your workspace.

`STATIC_ROOT` is the directory where the static files will be collected. It should be something like

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/example.com/staticfiles/'
```

If you don't want to hardcode the directory, you could do something like:

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles"),'
```

You would then configure your webserver (e.g. Nginx or Apache) to serve the files in the `STATIC_ROOT`.

Finally, `STATICFILES_DIRS` is a list of locations that Django will search for static files when you run `collectstatic`. The files will be copied from that directory to your `STATIC_ROOT`. Therefore you need to make sure that the `STATIC_ROOT` is not included in `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can create multiple 'static' folders for different applications of Django project and those can be used in development. But whenever you go to production servers and to serve the all static files from the same place then you need this functionality in which you can collect all static files from different directory to one directory out of your workplace.

```
project_name
-  project_name
   -   static
       -   static files goes here which are common
   -   __init__.py
   -   settings.py
   -   urls.py
-  application_name
   -   static
       -   static files goes here which are related to application only
   -   __init__.py
   -   settings.py
   -   urls.py
-  static - This is common place where all static files will be placed after collectstatic command for productions only.
```

According above structure you can understand you can server static files using different server like CDN.

Let me know if you are not satisfied with answer. Thanks.